# How to use Hover and click using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

Hi all i am using the `hover` and `click` function for a tool tip from here

[ToolTips](http://lyconic.com/resources/tools/formbubble#demos)

Now as per my requirement i would like to combine both `hover` and `click` event in one method. When `hover` i don't want to show `close` button but when user click i would like to show `close` button. How can i do this in one event can any help me or if any examples or samples please share

I tried this for `Tooltip` on `Click`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#foobar2').click(function() {
      var url = $(this).attr('href');       
      $(this).formBubble({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false
      });

      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

I tired this but not working can you edit please

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#foobar2').bind('mouseover click',function(e) {
    if(e.Type=='click')
    {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

      $(this).formBubble({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false
      });

      return false;
    }


      if(e.Type=='mouseover')
      {
      var url = $(this).attr('href');

      $(this).formBubble({
      closebutton:false;
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false
      });
      $.fn.formBubble.text('hover hover hover hover');
    }, function() { //mouse out
      var thisBubble = $.fn.formBubble.bubbleObject;

      $.fn.formBubble.close(thisBubble);
    });
      }   

    });});
</script>
```

hi i tried this but didn't work

```
 if(e.type=='mouseout')
{
var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
$(this).formBubble.hide()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of binding with: `.click(function(){ ... })`

bind with: `.bind('mouseover click',function(e){ ... })`

then inside the function use: `e.type` which will be a string determining what event type was triggered

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#foobar2').bind('mouseover click',function(e) {

      if(e.type == 'click'){
        // do some click event stuff
        var close = true 
      } else {
        // do some hover event stuff
        var close = false 
      }

      var url = $(this).attr('href');       
      $(this).formBubble({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        closeButton: close
      });

      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How can i disable close on hover

Comment: i think you add `closeButton: false` to the instantiating options object to disable the close button. My answer is updated to reflect this.

Comment: Hi Billy i have question how can i disable the tool tip when i take my control out side the image or control

Comment: bind a `mouseout` event in a similar way to the `mouseover event`, identify the button (by using a javascript console of some kind - I recommend firebug for firefox) and then with jQuery select the object you want to remove and use `.hide()` function - something like this: `$('#tool-tip-id').hide()`.

Comment: you need to `bind` the mouseout event, so either add it to your existing bind like this `.bind('mouseover mouseout click',function(e){ ... })` and then do a test on `e.type` or bind a new function like this `.bind('mouseout',function(){ ... })` where no test on type would be necessary

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post the required please i tried but i am unable to get the required